# How to create a file-encapsulated virtual hard drive on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, virtual-drive

I seek to create a virtual hard drive which will be readable and writable (by the host OS, *not* by a VirtualMachine) as an ordinary hard drive while being stored as a single file (or a pair, maybe) on a host partition. I'd also like it to be resizable. Actual image file format doesn't really matter (but would be nice if it could be something common). I use Windows XP. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Even though I've accepted an answer, I am still looking for more solutions. One another I've found and used successfully was WinMount which can mount a usual ZIP archive as a hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you happen have [Microsoft Virtual Server](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserversystem/virtualserver/) installed, you can mount disk images in its Virtual Hard Disk (VHD) format from the command line, using this command:

```
vhdmount /p /f file.vhd
```

If you don't have it, it's available as a [free download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=bc49c7c8-4840-4e67-8dc4-1e6e218acce4).  You can perform a "custom" install and only install the `vhdmount` utility if you'd like.

Comment: Note that this requires XP **Professional**.  It will not install on XP home.